# What's the origin of the "'ello, gov'nor" line?

Tags: dialogue, first-appearance, reference

This line is often used in TV shows, usually when a character is trying to use an english accent. He will use a british slang and say something along the lines of

> 'ello gov'nor!

Two examples from the top of my head, although there are a lot more:

- In New Girl S04E11, when Jess is going to London for Christmas, she is so excited that she tries to fake a British accent and says

  > 'ello gov'nor!
- In Community S03E16, Troy is busy and so Abed has to use the dreamatorium with Annie, who is supposed to play temporary Constable Geneva. She does it all wrong however, jumps out and says in a bad british accent:

  > Oy gov'nor, quantum spanner innit [..]

---

So it seems to be used as a gag to show that someone is really bad at British accents. Here's my question:

**What's the origin of this line and why is it so popular in shows/movies?**

Is it a reference to a famous movie scene? Or something that is just a common gag among Americans?

Bonus points if you can name the first show or movie where it was used.

Comment: It's a cockney expression that goes waaaaay back. Alfred P. Doolittle says it quite often in My Fair Lady (pygmalion). I'll research more but my thought is that that's the movie that propelled it as a meme. The OED cites it first from 1827. Oliver Twist was the first movie

Comment: Yeah, this has been used in films as a meme to some extent but it was actually something people said. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=%27Ello+gov%27na If you want the first instance of it used as a gag, you might want to adjust your question. :) Oh, and I'd guess it's popular because it sounds funny and is easy to say.

Comment: It is not a gag to show someone is bad at English accents. It is a stereotype of what certain speakers of British English say. It is also not a common gag among Americans. We don't go around saying that. *Maybe* to some British friends of ours, but again only to stereotype them.

Comment: "Bob's your uncle!"

Comment: @δοῦλος I'm pretty sure that, when on *The Daily Show*, John Oliver has used both 'ello gov'nor and Bob's your uncle on a relatively regular basis. Granted, he **is** British. But he's doing it as a mockery of what Americans think Brits say...

Comment: They say it quite often in ["Are you being served"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Are_You_Being_Served%3F)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [OED cites 'guv'](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/82777?redirectedFrom=guv#eid) and it's variants as entering the language in 1852 via Punch magazine. This is when the word 'guv-ner' was popularized.

I originally thought [Oliver Twist](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0040662/) (1948) was the first movie to use the line " 'ello guv-nor ". However I found an earlier movie [Convict 99](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0031178/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).

Here's [a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_HeoFHnLrU). The morning governors start at 40:11, they end 40:16.

Comment: Good find. You should include your info from the comment above. Seems relevant too.

Comment: @Ben: I just searched the OED, but can't find anything for "'ello guv-nah" or variants. What exactly is it listed under?

Comment: @Hugo try "guvnor". I'm still trying to get back into the OED. I found the reference at OED online, but couldn't access the information. I need to get to the library and use the resources there. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/guv%27nor I've got this much right now.

Comment: @Hugo Here's this as well. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/82777?rskey=sMeg5F&result=4# Though it doesn't list 'ello Guv-nah from Oliver Twist in 1844. That one, we know exists before these other examples.

Comment: @Ben Strange, OED online's first *guvnor* is from an 1852 *Punch* ("I say, Guvner...") and there's no "'ello guv-nah" mentioned. But "'ello guv-nah" isn't really a set phrase, just 'ello+guvnor. *Oliver Twist* was published in 1838 but I don't find any guvner or variants  [in the book](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/730/730-h/730-h.htm) and no "ello gunah" or variants at all in Google Books in the 19th century... If you can find an example in *Oliver Twist* or the OED 1827 cite, then the OED would be happy for the antedating!

Comment: I made a mistake about the publication date for Oliver Twist. And the novel he popularized "guv'ner" was actually Bleak House. The movie line is correct.

Comment: @Hugo my answer has been corrected. Thanks for catching my errors.

Comment: @BenPlont: For reference, the OED cite you claim is for Dickens' *Bleak House* is: 1852   *Punch* 2 Oct. 152/1 (caption)    Coster (to extremely genteel person). ‘I say, Guvner, give us a hist with this 'ere bilin' o' greens!’

Comment: @BenPlont: I checked [*Bleak House*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1023/1023-h/1023-h.htm) but find neither this line nor any character named Coster. The book was [published in 20 monthly instalments between March 1852 and September 1853](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleak_House), but it appears it was published under its own name (see the [first serial's cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleak_House#mediaviewer/File:Bleakhouse_serial_cover.jpg) and not in *Punch* magazine.

Comment: @BenPlont: Here is the [*Punch* magazine use](https://archive.org/stream/picturesoflifech02leecuoft#page/100/mode/1up/search/Guvner), in a later 1886 collection. As the OED says, it's a caption, and you can see the cartoon. It's clearly not Dickens, and the OED doesn't claim it to be.

Comment: @BenPlont: Finally, are you sure it was even used in the 1948 *Oliver Twist* film? This [script](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=oliver-twist-1948) makes no mention of guvnor or variants.

Comment: @Hugo I actually found an earlier movie Convict 99. Editing the answer.

Comment: @Hugo I pulled the reference to Dicken in Punch.

Comment: @Hugo Dickens and Punch shared a publisher. Both works were published in 1852, I made a mistake that Bleak House was published in Punch. Bleak House began being Published in March of 1852. [This](https://books.google.com/books?id=c_YPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA368&lpg=PA368&dq=%22bleak+house%22+%2B+guv+%2B+dickens&source=bl&ots=zEWEjqC-1L&sig=s96QrGpGHQ7NWutut5NyDa0IPdA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=akvnVIivA5TUoAS7toLoDg&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22bleak%20house%22%20%2B%20guv%20%2B%20dickens&f=false) is why I believe Bleak House should get the credit. I couldn't find a date for that cartoon.

Comment: The OED say the cartoon is from 2nd October 1852. Google Books sometime gets dates, titles and pages wrong, especially if full pages aren't shown, so they need to be verified. Good news! I checked [*Bleak House*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1023/1023-h/1023-h.htm) again, and character Phil Squod (Mr. George's assistant), who often drops vowels, says *guv'ner* 15 times (but not "'ello guv'nor"). The first is at the end of chapter 21: "Good night, guv'ner."

Comment: The earliest example I find of this line is from *[Harper's New Monthly Magazine](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dkZDAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA652&dq=%22+Good+night,+guv%27ner,%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pD7oVLfDBsa_ywOIuYG4DQ&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22%20Good%20night%2C%20guv'ner%22&f=false)*, which published chapters 20-22 in No. 29 -- October, 1852 --- Vol. 5. Unfortunately it's not clear if this was actually published before or after the 2nd October 1852 *Punch*.

Comment: *Harper's New Monthly Magazine* was published in the US. It was also serialised in the UK, and it seems a month earlier. [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleak_House#Original_publication) chapters 20-22 were published in instalment VII in September 1852. To confirm, I found a reference in a 5th September *Observer* newspaper to instalment VII of chapters 20-22, that said chapter 21 is about the Smallweed family (the chapter is titled "The Smallweed Family" in *Harper's* and elsewhere). Bingo, an antedating!